# Save json to to my local jsonl or .txt file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So in my function I have a stringified json

```
   const data = JSON.stringify((this.form.slice(0, this.turn)))
```

How do I save the "data" variable string to my output.jsonl file. I need to keep appending to it and I do not want to download it. I just want to keep writing to the file. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: How can I just save a darn string into output.jsonl please using vue

Comment: JSON is intended as a format to send data between two machines. It is not very good for storing data that will be modified and updated. Instead, you should use a database.

Comment: Also, if this code is running in someone's browser, you cannot save directly to a file on the server due to security concerns.

Comment: Forget JSON, how can I write a STRING?

Comment: Where do you want to write this string? I assume you want to write it to a file. Where will that file be saved? Since you are doing vue.js, I assume this code runs in a browser. You cannot write directly to a file on the computer where the browser runs (called the client) because it causes very serious security issues. You also cannot write directly to the computer where you request the page from (called the server) for the similar reasons. I suggest you do some research about the client and server and how they interact.

Comment: Even though you are loading code from your own machine into your browser, you should treat these as if they are two separate computers. This is the fundamental separation of client and server.